# Typescript says property doesn't exist though it does?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, graphql, apollo-client

I have the following code.

```
import { useQuery } from "@vue/apollo-composable";

const ACCOUNTS_QUERY = gql`
  {
    accounts {
      id
      name
      number
    }
  }
`;

interface Accounts {
  accounts: [
    {
      id: number;
      name: string;
      number: string;
    }
  ];
}

export default defineComponent({
  name: "AccountsView",
  setup() {
    const { result, loading, error } = useQuery<Accounts>(ACCOUNTS_QUERY);

    return {
      accounts: result.accounts,
    }
```

Here I get TS2339: Property 'accounts' does not exist on type 'Ref<Accounts | undefined>' in the return.

Now if I swap the return statement for:

```
    return {
      result,
    }
```

I can access `result.accounts` in the template and iterate over it with `v-for`. Why can't I return `result.accounts`?

Comment: quick fix: const { result, loading, error }: any = useQuery<Accounts>(ACCOUNTS_QUERY)

Comment: @Ar26 - May as well just not use TypeScript at all.

Answer (score 0):

The type that is returned is Ref<Accounts | undefined>, but you are using the result as an Accounts type. I don't know what vue does when you return a Ref (might be that it resolves it in some way, but I never worked with vue).

I think that what you are trying to do is an asynchronous call, so at the moment you want to access the props of result, result is not resolved yet (asynchronous backend call via graphQL).

You could add a break point and see whats inside of result at that very moment (or use console.log() for that)

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems:

1. According to [the documentation](https://v4.apollo.vuejs.org/guide-composable/query.html#usequery), the `result` property on the return value of `@vue/apollo-composable`'s `useQuery` is a `Ref`, but you're not using its `value` property when trying to get at `accounts` (it should be `result.value.accounts`, not just `result.accounts`).
2. Since loading the data is asynchronous, `result.value` may be `undefined`; the type of `result` is `Ref<Accounts | undefined>`, not `Ref<Accounts>`. You have to narrow that type for TypeScript to know it's valid to look for an `accounts` property on it.

So:

```typescript
const { result, loading, error } = useQuery<Accounts>(ACCOUNTS_QUERY);
if (result.value) { // Does the narrowing
    result.value.accounts
    //            ^? (property) Accounts.accounts: [{ id: number; name: string; number: string; }]
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: As for your first comment, I import `useQuery` from `@vue/apollo-composable`. I have updated my question with this relevant info.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, I went with another solution.

```
  data() {
    const accounts: Account[] = [];

    return {
      accounts,
    };
  },
  beforeMount() {
    useQuery<Accounts>(ACCOUNTS_QUERY).onResult(
      (handler) => (this.accounts = handler.data.accounts)
    );
  },
```

Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.